# How can I iterate through a pandas dataframe two-by-two, open some .txt files, perform an action, then move to the next?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, similarity, trigonometry

I am working with .txt files of SEC data, and trying to compare them.  Essentially, what I have done is sorted them so I am sure that each company_name in my dataframe has exactly 2 with that name.

What I want to do is find those, pull in the files (which I already have) via the extension, and perform my comparison via cosine similarity, then move on to the next two.  I am just not sure how to do this sort of iteration besides the simple i = 0, i+1, etc. and was wondering if there was an easier way.  I have provided an image sample of the frame below for reference.

I am sure this is much easier than it seems right now, and I am just missing an obvious pandas command or something.  Thanks for your time, and I hope if it is something simple you can forgive my mind slipping like this.

[Here is an example of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxxsa.png)

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Also, post your example data in the text of your question, rather than as an image, so that it's easier for other users to reproduce.

Comment: This would be easier to write up an answer for if you included some sample code to generate the data frame. I will point you at the pandas.DataFrame.iterrows() method which returns a generator that iterates over each row.